# How to bitwise flip an char array by diagonal effectively in C/C++ or Cuda?

Tags: c++, cuda, bit-manipulation, diagonal, memory-layout

I have a char array `char input[8] = "abcdabcd"`, and I want to bitwise flip it by diagonal, which mean
`input`:

```
input[0] == 'a': 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
input[1] == 'b': 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
input[2] == 'c': 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
input[3] == 'd': 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
input[4] == 'a': 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
input[5] == 'b': 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
input[6] == 'c': 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
input[7] == 'd': 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

`output`:

```
                   a b c d a b c d
output[0] ==   0 : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
output[1] == 255 : 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
output[2] == 255 : 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
output[3] ==   0 : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
output[4] ==   0 : 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
output[5] ==  17 : 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
output[6] == 102 : 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
output[7] == 170 : 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

It is obvious that we can use two loop combined with bitwise or operation to set the target bit one by one, however, this mean we need at least `64 * n` operations, which I think is not effectively.
Since the input and output are just about reading memory in different directions (by row or by column), are there any more effectively way?
Besides, I think it is quite  acceptable and make sense to do this operation based on special memory layout, or change the number or characters in array.
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is *matrix transposition*. You can google algorithms for that, it's a pretty popular thing in Matrix Theory.

Comment: Hi @DeiDei, actually I want to do some further bitwise operations on output, somethings like `~output[0] & output[1]`. Actually I think this bitwise transform may be a bit different from Matrix transposition, since maybe we can utilize some memory operation, but personally I am not sure whether we can do it in this way. Overall, thank you very much!

Comment: "Since the input and output are just about reading memory in different directions" -- that would only be true if the hardware could support byte sized memory transactions with arbitrary bit alignment. It does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code based on the trick from [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/). Although it is CPU code, it can be easily transformed into parallel CUDA code.

This code itself is for transposing bitmap of arbitrary sizes. What you really need is the code for transposing an `uint64_t` x to another `uint64_t` y.

```
using BitBlock = uint8_t;
using BitBlocks = std::vector<BitBlock>;

void FPTransMap::transpose_bitmap( BitBlocks& bitmap, size_type blocks_per_row )
{
    assert( bitmap.size() % blocks_per_row == 0 );
    assert( ( bitmap.size() / blocks_per_row ) % 8 == 0 );

    BitBlocks transposed( bitmap.size() );
    size_type nrow = bitmap.size() / blocks_per_row, row_blocks = nrow / 8;
    for ( index_type i = 0; i < row_blocks; ++i ) {
        for ( index_type j = 0; j < blocks_per_row; ++j ) {
            uint64_t x = ( uint64_t( bitmap[   i * 8       * blocks_per_row + j ] ) << 56 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 1 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) << 48 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 2 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) << 40 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 3 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) << 32 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 4 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) << 24 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 5 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) << 16 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 6 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) <<  8 ) |
                         ( uint64_t( bitmap[ ( i * 8 + 7 ) * blocks_per_row + j ] ) );
            uint64_t y = (x & 0x8040201008040201LL) |
                        ((x & 0x0080402010080402LL) <<  7) |
                        ((x & 0x0000804020100804LL) << 14) |
                        ((x & 0x0000008040201008LL) << 21) |
                        ((x & 0x0000000080402010LL) << 28) |
                        ((x & 0x0000000000804020LL) << 35) |
                        ((x & 0x0000000000008040LL) << 42) |
                        ((x & 0x0000000000000080LL) << 49) |
                        ((x >>  7) & 0x0080402010080402LL) |
                        ((x >> 14) & 0x0000804020100804LL) |
                        ((x >> 21) & 0x0000008040201008LL) |
                        ((x >> 28) & 0x0000000080402010LL) |
                        ((x >> 35) & 0x0000000000804020LL) |
                        ((x >> 42) & 0x0000000000008040LL) |
                        ((x >> 49) & 0x0000000000000080LL);
            transposed[ ( j * 8 ) * row_blocks + i ]     = uint8_t( ( y >> 56 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 1 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( ( y >> 48 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 2 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( ( y >> 40 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 3 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( ( y >> 32 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 4 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( ( y >> 24 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 5 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( ( y >> 16 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 6 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( ( y >> 8 ) & 0xFF );
            transposed[ ( j * 8 + 7 ) * row_blocks + i ] = uint8_t( y & 0xFF );
        }
    }
    std::swap( bitmap, transposed );
}
```

Comment: The detail of my case is a bit different, but this algorithm is actually what I want! Thanks!

Comment: Besides, does this algorithm have a name?

Comment: I don't know if this hack actually has a name. I found it mentioned in a research paper and read it on Hackers Delight.

Comment: @yhf8377Thanks! Could you tell me the title of that paper?

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu Actually there is a ready-made code chunk for transpose 8x8 bit matrix! See [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/transpose8.c.txt)